# Eclipse Egit: Update a github fork to merge changes of master repo?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have forked a github repo. Now my worked repo is out of sync with the original repo.

I understand that I need to do a merge, but how to do this with Eclipse git is a bit unclear to me.

Question: How do I update my fork to include changes made to the original repo made by the owner?

---

**Edit 1:** I've added another remote. But I don't see any Pull buttons on the context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the second url under upstream to push your changes. The first one ist just for fetching (see the green/red arrows ;-)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? Didn't the author of the question want to  do a pull from upstream instead of pushing to it?

Answer (score 5):

You do the merge on your local machine and then push the result from your local machine to your own github repo. There is no way to update your github repo directly on the server.

To do that, add that original github repo as a new remote. This is described in the [egit user manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Remote_Configuration). Choose "configure for fetch" instead and give it the URI of the original repo. Afterwards you can simply use the context menu "Pull" on that new remote node to fetch and merge all the new stuff. After finishing the merge, you "Push to upstream", which is your own github repo.

Comment: I will just add that after pushing your changes to YOUR github repo you can open a pull request on GIthub for the author of the original repo to merge your changes in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. please see my attached screenshot.